# Does Allah Ta'la refer to Himself as "He" in Arabic?

Tags: allah, arabic

In the English translation of the Quran, Allah Ta'la refers to Himself as "He"

Is the word also "He" or "Him" (the male gender) in the Arabic text as well?

If yes, why?

Thanks and Jazak Allah khair